# checking if file exists in s3 bucket after uploading and then deleting file locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I use the line of code below to send data to a s3 bucket:

```
response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
```

After this line executes, I want to check if the file actually exists in the bucket. If it exists, I want to delete the version that is stored locally.

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use `HEAD` action to check whether the object is present in the bucket at the location, the key or "object_name" in your case, you specified while uploading it.

Here's the link to the doc -> https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object

If this call return `200 OK`, then object exists and you can use this check to then delete the object that is present locally.

If the object doesn't exist in S3, then the `HEAD` call will give `404 Not Found`